# Why does my float elements not working properly at 40% + 60% width settings?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following CSS and HTML set:

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

nav{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

aside{
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

section{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    
  </header>
  <nav>
    
  </nav>
  <aside>
    
  </aside>
  <section>
    
  </section>
</body>
```

But I'm confused as to how my `<aside>` and `<section>` are not side by side even after setting them to float properties.  I set `<aside>` to `width: 40%` and `<section>` to `width: 60%`.  Shouldn't they add up to `100%` and fill the entire webpage horizontally across?

Comment: I haven't added any paddings or margins also.

Comment: Try applying `box-sizing: border-box;` to both of them. It's important to remember that borders add to the width, so your elements are actually 2px bigger than 40% and 60%. The property I mentioned will restrict padding/borders from affecting element width.

Comment: oh, I didn't account for border width!  thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of 4px of extra space is being covered by borders in aside and section boxes. Just provide `box-sizing: border-box` to both;

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

nav{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

aside{
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    
  </header>
  <nav>
    
  </nav>
  <aside>
    
  </aside>
  <section>
    
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you account for the browsers preset margin and padding. Try resetting them.

```
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```