# How to Have Two Fieldsets On The Right And Left Side Of A Page And Then Put Buttons Down The Middle Between Them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an HTML, CSS, and JavaScript tutorial and I can handle the js needed... I have 2 fieldsets on each side of the page but I need the button in between them... I can't figure out how to do that. Here is my code:

```css
body {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Bradley's Hand", cursive
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 450px
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 450px
}

#input {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="html.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <fieldset id="left">
    <p id="output">TEST</p>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="input">
    <input type="button" id="doctype" value="<!DOCTYPE html>">
    <input type="button" id="html" value="<html>">
    <input type="button" id="head" value="<head>">
    <input type="button" id="title" value="<title>">
    <input type="button" id="css" value="<link rel='stylesheet'>">
  </div>&nbsp;
  <fieldset id="right">
    <p id="lesson">TEST</p>
  </fieldset>
  <script src="html.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what it looks like now:

[What my code looks like!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reVO7.png)

I need the buttons between the fieldset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this I would use flex. The closest to what you have would be to make the input div a flex display with flex-direction set to column. Additionally I  used box-sizing: border-box on the floated divs so that their widths are actually 40%. Read more here:

[Why does my float elements not working properly at 40% + 60% width settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197341/why-does-my-float-elements-not-working-properly-at-40-60-width-settings)

It's not perfect but it's a start:

```css
body {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Bradley's Hand", cursive
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 450px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#right {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 450px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 18%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="html.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <div style="position: relative">
  <fieldset id="left">
    <p id="output">TEST</p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="right">
    <p id="lesson">TEST</p>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="input">
    <input type="button" id="doctype" value="<!DOCTYPE html>">
    <input type="button" id="html" value="<html>">
    <input type="button" id="head" value="<head>">
    <input type="button" id="title" value="<title>">
    <input type="button" id="css" value="<link rel='stylesheet'>">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="html.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

--- EDIT ---

Personally I would use flex both all three columns. It would look like this:

```css
body {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Bradley's Hand", cursive
}

#columns {
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 40%;
  line-height: 450px;
}

#right {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 40%;
  line-height: 450px;
}

#input {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 18%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input input {
flex: 1;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="html.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <div id="columns">
  <fieldset id="left">
    <p id="output">TEST</p>
  </fieldset>
  <div id="input">
    <input type="button" id="doctype" value="<!DOCTYPE html>">
    <input type="button" id="html" value="<html>">
    <input type="button" id="head" value="<head>">
    <input type="button" id="title" value="<title>">
    <input type="button" id="css" value="<link rel='stylesheet'>">
  </div>
  <fieldset id="right">
    <p id="lesson">TEST</p>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
  <script src="html.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This has the advantage of having the middle column always perfectly fill the space between the outer columns

Comment: This centers the buttons where I want them but the fieldset on the right gets pushed down...  Is there a way to do this... I kind of want 3 columns.

Comment: See the seccond snippet. That should work

Comment: Thank you! This works! Also, you reply fast!